# C++ & DirectX - geometry question

Tags: c++, performance, geometry, directx

***I am working on my own 3d engine and have the following question:***

I have an abstract object, that handles geometry *(vertices and faces)*. It uses internal storage for this geometry, allows editing and my renderer object has a method `RenderGeometry`.

With this design my rendering process includes a `geometry caching` step. So, renderer has some map-like container

```
std::map<Geometry*, CachedGeometry*> map;
```

and here `Geometry` stands for my own geometry storage and `CachedGeometry` means a pair of hardware-specific index and vertex buffers, which can then be displayed (in case of DirectX 9 these would be `IDirect3D9VertexBuffer*` and `IDirect3D9IndexBuffer*`.

---

And, well, everything looks fine and is extremely convenient. Still, every `Geometry*` rendering call has a huge overhead - time to locate that `Geometry*` object in my internal storage and only then render the `CachedGeometry*`.

*In case of simple scenes this overhead was, of course, minimal, but when I attempted to render a landscape with a vast amount of little spatial objects (patches), the profiling showed that about 20% of time spent in rendering was actually used for `std::map` lookups.*

Hash-based containers (`boost::unordered_map`, actually) showed even worse performance *(why?)* and that percentage raised to 35%.

---

So - to sum everything up - what should I do in this situation? I guess this design is really comfortable and *"appropriate"*, but has abstraction performance penalty.

I think that probably I should try the "nastier" approach and introduce methods like `StoreGeometry` in my renderer, which would return object index (`int`, for example), so that `RenderGeometry` method would look like `RenderGeometry(int stored_geometry_index)`.

Although this looks very bad, probably it could help me in reducing the lookups overhead.

***What do you think? Maybe some alternative approach? What do modern engines do about geometry precaching?***

Comment: Can't the `Geometry*` just hold a pointer to its `CachedGeometry` instance, avoiding the lookup entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised that `std::map` is performing so bad. It might be worthwile ask a question (search for existing answers first!) specifically about std::map performance on pointers.

Given that `Geometry` and `CachedGeometry` are objects that you control, you can do whatever you want to maintain links between them. One way is to make the link 2-way: Both Geometry and CachedGeometry have pointers to each other, and if CachedGeomitry is destroyed, it tells `Geometry` to null the reference to it's `CachedGeometry`. If your app is single threaded this could be very simple. If not, it is still doable but will require you to think how  you handle(or prevent) situations when an object is deleted in mid air.